# Atom auto tslint detection

Tags: atom-editor, tslint

Recently I opened Angular 2 project in my freshly installed atom editor(with https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript and linter). 
I was surprised with the fact that atom automatically detected tslint.json file in project root directory and apply those rules to highlight errors.

Can someone explain to me, how did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

The linter for TypeScript is [linter-tslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-tslint), which requires [tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) as a dependency.

tslint looks for tslint.json files to load rules.

Comment: Is there a quick fix option for atom that can make the fixes automatically as well? Like swapping in single quotes for double, etc?